# accessing data of multiprocessing.pool.MapResult issue python pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am running into this issue:
so after I use pool such as the following:

```py
with Pool(4) as p:  
        first_nei_index_a = np.expand_dims([p.map_async(getFNThreaded, atom) for atom in occupied], axis=(0,1))
        p.close()
```

and then when I print first_nei_index_a, it seems like it generates correctly the output as such: look below:

*the problem with that is that object is not iterable, and I need to access this data, but it's not letting me at all because arrays that will be used have to be integer or boolean type. Any clue on how to overcome this? in other words, I want to do operations on first_nei_index[:,:,:]
many thanks in advance.

```
[[[<multiprocessing.pool.MapResult object at 0x2adf35df79a0>
   <multiprocessing.pool.MapResult object at 0x2adf35df79d0>
   <multiprocessing.pool.MapResult object at 0x2adf35df7c10>
   <multiprocessing.pool.MapResult object at 0x2adf35df7d30>
   <multiprocessing.pool.MapResult object at 0x2adf35df7e50>
   <multiprocessing.pool.MapResult object at 0x2adf35df7f70>
   <multiprocessing.pool.MapResult object at 0x2adf35dff0d0>
   <multiprocessing.pool.MapResult object at 0x2adf35dff1f0>
```

Comment: Instead of commenting, edit your question if you spot a mistake. To get the result of `map_async`, you need to do `.get()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Charchit. .get() doesn't work. Numpy.ndarry has no attribute "get"

Comment: You most probably tried to do that on the whole array. You have to iterate over the array and do `.get` for each element. Post the code where you tried to do `.get`

Comment: yes you are absolutely right. I was doing,                                                                                    first_nei_index_a = first_nei_index_a.get()                                                                                 obviously that didn't work, so I am iterating through the array by                                         for atom in first_nei_index_a:                                                                                                      
      atom.get()                             but that still didn't work, no errors but never finished!

Comment: Note that `.get()` blocks until all tasks in the pool are complete. If it never unblocks then there might be some issue with `getFNThreaded` function.